# Shared Preference Empty On Next run

Tags: android-studio, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I have A SharedPreference That I want to save an array list for the next time I open the app. But The next time I start the app it comes up as empty. I execute the save onDestroy because I dont want to push a button. I dont know whats going on. Any help would be appreciated.

I run LoadData() Method inside onCreate() Method.

```
public void LoadData(){
   SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("SavedArrayList",MODE_PRIVATE);

   Gson gson = new Gson();
   String json = sp.getString("Arraylist", null);
   Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ListItems>>() {}.getType();
        if (json != null)items = gson.fromJson(json, type);
   }
```

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
   SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("SavedArrayList",MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

   Gson gson = new Gson();
   String json = gson.toJson(items);
   editor.putString("Arraylist", json);
   editor.apply();
   super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: store this Arraylist in OnPause() instead of onDestory() and also load data in onResume().

Answer (score 0):

All I did was moved it to onPause and onResume now it works fine.